# Proguard obfuscation crashes app in getView

Tags: android, crash, proguard, obfuscation

Spent several hours and was unable to prevent the app crashing after obfuscation. Also searched around to no avail. If someone could give me a hint in the right direction I'd appreciate it.
The crash starts where getView get (Unknown Source)

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1019)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:663)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at a.getDrawable(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintManager.getDrawable(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintManager.getDrawable(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at roncada.skyweather.DropZoneAdapter.getView(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2222)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1774)
```

The code where it starts:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        DropZoneAdapter adapter = new DropZoneAdapter(getActivity(), DZS);
        getListView().setAdapter(adapter);

    } //end postexecute
```

then in the adapter:

class DropZoneAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
public DropZoneAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<DropZoneFragment.DZ_Row> sites) {
    super(context, R.layout.row_layout, sites);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Get the data item for this position
```

and it breaks in the convertView.

Here's my proguard rules:

```
-dontpreverify
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic
#-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class android.support.v4.internal.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.internal.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v7.internal.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.internal.** { *; }
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
#-keep public class * extends android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontwarn com.google.common.**
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
```

Would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably protect your `Fragment` from obfuscation.

```
-keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment
```

Comment: i tried it but no luck. I believe it has to do the way the Fragment gets the context from the Activity but can't figure this out.

Comment: @WalterRoncada, Post your `convertView` method so we can see how the `Context` is being used

Comment: There was a bug in the code, in a obscure if condition that was passing 0 instead of the R.id.int. I had to use proguard's mapping.txt to track it down.  Thanks for trying to help and in a sense it helped to look back at the convertView.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to keep resource ID:

```
# Keep resource files ID
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}
```

Comment: Also tried your suggestion but the crash error is the same.